Does the GRPC server-side streaming response require writer->WritesDone() or writer->Finish()？
I have a server-side sync streaming GRPC service. When executing the writer->Write(reply) method on the server, I am thinking about a question. If write fails, that is, when it returns false, do I need to close the streaming service at this time? Or is it enough to just return the wrong grpc status? This is enough to confuse me. If I have some messages to send to the client, when the network is abnormal, I just return the error status without closing the server stream. When the network is restored, will there be any changes to this stream?
Currently my server sync stream is just returning an exception status and not closing it using writer->WritesDone() and writer->Finish(). It still works fine so I'm confused.

When would write fail on server side? I think it's when client has closed the connection, so there is no one to respond to. You should in that case, instead of returning error code, close the connection. Note that this is purely based on my assumption that Write fails when client has disconnected.

What will happen if I don't close the connection? Currently, my code does not have any statement about closing the connection, and no exception has occurred. But I don't know what impact will it have if I don't close the connection?

Not sure really.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
